# Azure Policy - deny changes via user interface

Tags: azure, user-interface, terraform, policy

I have a policy that denies changes on resources that have a terraform tag:

```
    {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "tags['source']",
              "exists": "true"
            },
            {
              "field": "tags['source']",
              "equals": "terraform"
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "deny"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {}
    }
```

Currently this policy is blocking all changes on terraform managed resources, but I want to be able to do changes via terraform but not in the azure ui.

Is there a way in Azure Policies, to check if a change was made via Azure ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way in Azure Policies, to check if a change was made via Azure ui?

No, the policy prevents you from making any changes to the scope, regardless of the method you use, such as **UI** or **tools**.

The scope you are creating the resource is the same scope applied to policy as well, so resource creation will block if you are trying to create a resource regardless of method you are using **UI** and **Tools**.

I assigned the same policy to the resource group. When I attempted to create a **VNet** with the tag **source: terraform**, the resource deployment was blocked by the policy both on the **UI portal** and **Terraform**

**UI portal**

[image]

**Terraform**

[image]

To deploy using **Terraform** without blocking, avoid passing the same tag. Conversely, to enable blocking via the **UI**, make sure to pass the same tags.

[image]

For more details about the **type: deny** condition in azure policy, refer to [Azure Policy effect type: deny](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#deny).